# Android 'make' error: error: too few arguments to function 'belle_sip_multipart_body_handler_new'

Tags: android, android-ndk, cmake, makefile, linphone

When executing `sudo make` on an Android project (linphone) I experiencing an error stating:

```
jni/..//submodules/linphone/build/android/../../coreapi/chat.c: In function 'linphone_chat_message_process_response_from_post_file':
jni/..//submodules/linphone/build/android/../../coreapi/chat.c:269:4: error: too few arguments to function 'belle_sip_multipart_body_handler_new'
bh=belle_sip_multipart_body_handler_new(linphone_chat_message_file_transfer_on_progress, msg, first_part_bh);
```

```
In file included from jni/..//submodules/linphone/build/android/../../coreapi/../../belle-sip/include/belle-sip/belle-sip.h:44:0,
                 from jni/..//submodules/linphone/build/android/../../coreapi/../include/sal/sal.h:35,
                 from jni/..//submodules/linphone/build/android/../../coreapi/private.h:35,
                 from jni/..//submodules/linphone/build/android/../../coreapi/chat.c:26:

make[1]: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/linphone/chat.o] Error 1
```

```
make: *** [generate-libs] Error 2
```

Anyone have any idea how to resolve this?

### Source:

https://github.com/TheBaobabTeam/linphone-android

Comment: Is this **single** error message or several ones?

Comment: It is several errors during one 'make' - I have included the entire process from 'make' to 'error here for further clarity: 

http://pastebin.com/9AP4X7dy

(thank you for your input!)

Comment: No needs to *ping*. If someone who has knowledge about this topic will find the question, he would answer the question. Instead of ping, try to **improve** your question. E.g., combine 3 parts of output, into one listing (as you say, it is the single log). *The better question is, the more chances for it to be asked.*

Comment: Ok. I'll update momentarily.